# how do I get a detailed Plsql Error review

Tags: java, oracle, spring-boot, plsql

I have this api that calls a procedure by name and execute it, it's working fine, but when I test with a stored procedure that has an error it gives me a general error message, how do I make it provide me a detailed error message?

This is the code:

```
@PostMapping("/procedures/{procedureName}")
    public ResponseEntity<String> executeProcedure(@PathVariable String procedureName) {
        String sql = "{CALL " + procedureName + "}"; 
        try (Connection conn = jdbcTemplate.getDataSource().getConnection();
             CallableStatement stmt = conn.prepareCall(sql)) {
            stmt.execute(); // execute the procedure
            return ResponseEntity.ok("Procedure executed successfully");
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).body(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

Get a detailed error message.

Comment: Define "general" and "detailed" in this context.  Does the procedure throw what you consider to be a detailed error message when called from, say, SQL Developer?  If so, what is the difference between that error message and the error message you are getting here?  It's hard to guess whether the procedure simply doesn't throw a sufficiently detailed error (because, say, it has a `when others` exception handler), whether you want to look at the chain of SQLExceptions, or something else.

Comment: What i'am trying to build is a spring boot web application that calls stored procedures, execute them, if it's correct it print 'correct', if not i want to get a detailed report like the line containing the error etc, i really need help in this project, i can contact you for more information.

Comment: I understand that.  But I still don’t understand exactly what details you are missing.  For example, I can write a stored procedure which doesn’t return a meaningful error when it fails.  Or I can create one that gives a meaningful stack trace. Hence the question- does the procedure throw what you consider a “detailed” error when executed from SQL Developer?  What details are you missing in your app?

Comment: For exemple i have this stored procedure that inserts user in users table, when i change the table name and compile it with SQL developer it says "table dosen't exist" but if i execute it with my app it says "PLS-00905: object SYSTEM.INSERT_USER is not valid", i get this error for almost any wrong procedure
`create or replace NONEDITIONABLE PROCEDURE insert_user (
  p_username IN users.username%TYPE,
  p_email IN users.email%TYPE,
  p_password IN users.password%TYPE
) AS
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO eusers (username, email, password)
  VALUES (p_username, p_email, p_password);
  COMMIT;
END;`

Comment: OK, so that's helpful information that should be added to your question.  Are you really worried about compilation errors though?  You should basically never encounter a compilation error in production code-- that implies that something has failed catastrophically during the deploy process.  Applications would normally only concern themselves with runtime errors which should be vastly more common.  If you really wanted to, you could query `all_errors` for the object in question to see the compilation errors and report that information but that would be very, very, very unusual.

Comment: Sadly, that's what i trying to do, it's like creating a SQL PLUS web app

Comment: OK.  So, again, that's very useful information to edit into the question.  But take a look at how `SQL*Plus` works.  If you issue a DDL statement (your `create or replace procedure`) you just get back a message saying that the object failed to compile.  If you want to see the compilation errors, you have to issue a second command `show errors` which queries `all_errors` to show you the errors.  If you try to run an invalid procedure, you just get the ORA-00905 error you posted.  It doesn't tell you what the compilation errors are.

Comment: Incidentally, never, never, never, never create objects in the `SYS` or `SYSTEM` schema.  Those are reserved for Oracle.  Create your own schema.  Those are special.  Occasionally, code behaves differently in those schemas in a way that is contrary to "normal" documentation.

Comment: So, sir, what do you suggest? My purpose is that have many PLSQL blocks, i just want to build this app and compile then to see if they are still valid or not. Ofc with compilation error identification.

Comment: If you are only trying to determine whether stored PL/SQL blocks you have previously created are still valid, query `all_objects` to get the `status` and `all_errors` to get the errors.  Probably after doing a recompile on the schema.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking if your code is catching an exception it is a good habit to print out a full stacktrace. Usually with the logger. It has a convenient interface to print the stacktrace of exception.

**Solution**

Add Lombok plugin and dependency

Add following annotation to your class

```
@Slf4j
```

Add logging to the catch block

```
} catch (SQLException e) {
    log.error("SQL exception: {}, e);
    return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).body(e.getMessage());
}
```